# How to determine if a Service account has login as batch rights to a server

Tags: windows, security

I tried the following command

```
net user {serviceaccount} /domain
```

but the command only told me which machines the service account could run on, not whether it had Logon as Batch rights.

is it possible to determine this without any extraordinary rights such as have Remote access?

Comment: are we to assume this is Windows?

Comment: With a command `net user ... /domain` that's probably a rather safe bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the current user you can use `whoami /priv` to determine the privileges. To determine the privileges of another account, you need something like Sysinternals' [AccessChk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922).

```
accesschk -a ACCOUNT *
```

Comment: I want to check to see if Service Acct "A" has Logon As Batch rights on Server "B". Do I have to run this SysInternals command on the server "B" to determine this? I presume so.

Comment: Yes. `AccessChk` does not have a "remote" option. If you want to run it remotely, you're going to need something like [`PsExec`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553).

Comment: Specifically, `AccessChk` will return the string `SeBatchLogonRight` if it has the privilege.